# Data on inflation target on different countries around the world

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, inflation, central-banking

Does someone know if there's a page, like a "global bank" online page, where one could see the *inflation target* for different countries?

For example, in x country, for x' year, the inflation target is $x''\%\pm 1$.

I know that this information can be found on the different central bank's online pages for each country, and if one would like to know about them, then one would need to check each page of them, one at a time.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you mean inflation target

Comment: @1muflon1 ah. Ok, I'll edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [CentralBankNews.info](https://www.centralbanknews.info/p/inflation-targets.html).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help.

Comment: @VerónicaRmz. If you think this answer answered your question please consider accepting it

Comment: @1muflon1 Ok, haven't checked the link yet tho.

Comment: @1muflon1 done.